# How to embed a Youtube Video using the URL inserted from an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, youtube, embed

so I'm trying to have a youtube video embedded in my webpage. To embed it I need to use the URL that the user inserted in an input. What would be the jquery/JavaScript I need to use to embed the video?

Comment: please show us what you have tried. The generic embed code is easy enough to get ... and really quite simple to modify. Getting a value from an input is also very simple and well documented all over the place. It is expected of you to show some effort to solve problems yourself before asking here and you will get a lot more help by showing some effort was made on your part

Comment: function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

var myId;

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#embed1').click(function () {
    var myUrl = $('#URL1').val();
    myId = getId(myUrl);
    
    $('#youtubeID1').html(myId);
    
    $('#youtube1').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
});

Comment: Please update the question with that code ...so it can be formatted and read. Comment blocks are not good for big blobs of code

Answer (score 0):

Create an iframe

```
<iframe id="myVid" width="420" height="315"
    src="">
</iframe>
```

Then grab the input from the user preferably the url and pass it with jquery

```
$('#myVid').attr('src', "user-supplied-url")
```

Comment: i tried that, but it just said, that the file was unable to be found

Comment: Can you please post what you have code wise and I can take a better look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Formatted code from @theDoctor

```
function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
var myId;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#embed1').click(function() {
        var myUrl = $('#URL1').val();
        myId = getId(myUrl);
        $('#youtubeID1').html(myId);
        $('#youtube1').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    });
});
```